# Python regex: rename all files except those with today's date in the name

Tags: python, regex, file, rename

I'm attempting to rename all files in a folder and remove spaces from the filename. All files have today's date in YY-mm-dd format in the name. Below is what I've managed to create thus far.

However, running that gives me a "TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not _sre.SRE_Pattern"

```python
import os
import datetime
import re
today = datetime.datetime.now()
path = "/some/path/"
regex = re.compile(".*" + today.strftime("(%Y-%m-%d)") + ".*(.log$)", re.IGNORECASE)
for file in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(file.startswith(regex), file.replace(" ","_")
```

Note: I am aware that in its current state, it looks for today's date rather than all dates except today. I've left it as-is for testing and will invert match the regex once it works.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is right in the error, the argument for `startswith` has to be a string, not a compiled regex pattern. So basically it's telling you `startswith` can't take a regex pattern as an argument. But hey- that's what regex is for!

You should use the regex pattern `^` to signify the start of the line, and then match the filename to that pattern.

Here's a rough example:

```
...
regex = re.compile("^.*" + today.strftime("(%Y-%m-%d)") + ".*(.log$)", re.IGNORECASE)
for file in os.listdir(path):
     if regex.match(file): 
         # do something
```

Comment: Doing it this way no longer throws an error, however if I place print(file) below the if statement, I get no results.

Answer (score 0):

Your file.startswith(regex) will return either True or False.  I think what you want is to rename files that match your regex. You need another "if" statement under your for loop to check whether or not the file name starts with the regex, then you need to run the os.rename:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.starstwith(regex):
        os.rename(file, file.replace(" ", "_"))
```

Comment: I think `if file.starstwith(regex):` will throw the same TypeError, since `regex` is a compiled regex pattern (but needs to be a string or tuple).